# Getting data from html string and push to array

Tags: javascript

So i'm making a post request and the response is a string of html and i'm trying to get the data from the `"dropUser"` part of the html string but i'm having a little trouble and was hoping maybe someone could help me or point me in the right direction.

My goal is to get the data from the `"dropUser"` html string and push them to an array.

For an example the ID 4289985, and username 'MeowCat i want to get all of them and push to an array.

```js
let str = `<div id="container_user">
  <div class="user_count">
    <div class="bcell">
      Online <span class="ucount back_theme">4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="online_user">
    <div onclick="dropUser(this,5,'ChatAveBot',1,1,'ZZ','','0','');" class="avtrig user_item ">
      <div class="user_item_avatar"><img class="avav acav avsex nosex " src="/avatar/default_avatar.png" /> </div>
      <div class="user_item_data">
        <p class="username user ">ChatAveBot</p>
      </div>
      <div class="user_item_icon icrank"><img src="default_images/rank/bot.svg" class="list_rank" title="Bot" /></div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="dropUser(this,3754679,'Fantastic',1,0,'ZZ','','14','');" class="avtrig user_item ">
      <div class="user_item_avatar"><img class="avav acav avsex nosex " src="/avatar/avatar_user3754679_1638955491.jpg" /> </div>
      <div class="user_item_data">
        <p class="username bcolor1 bnfont7">Fantastic</p>
        <p class="text_xsmall bustate bellips">TheDD7デイビスになる =</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="dropUser(this,4290052,'cefefef',0,0,'AU','','13','');" class="avtrig user_item ">
      <div class="user_item_avatar"><img class="avav acav avsex nosex " src="/avatar/default_guest.png" /> </div>
      <div class="user_item_data">
        <p class="username user ">cefefef</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="dropUser(this,4289985,'MeowCat',0,0,'AU','','13','');" class="avtrig user_item ">
      <div class="user_item_avatar"><img class="avav acav avsex nosex glob_av" src="/avatar/default_guest.png" /> </div>
      <div class="user_item_data">
        <p class="username user ">MeowCat</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>`;

let data = [];
//let info = str.split(`'`).forEach(e => e.includes("dropUser"));
console.log(str.split(`'`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
const htmlStr = `<div id="container_user">
  <div class="user_count">
    <div class="bcell">
      Online <span class="ucount back_theme">4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="online_user">
    <div onclick="dropUser(this,5,'ChatAveBot',1,1,'ZZ','','0','');" class="avtrig user_item ">
      <div class="user_item_avatar"><img class="avav acav avsex nosex " src="/avatar/default_avatar.png" /> </div>
      <div class="user_item_data">
        <p class="username user ">ChatAveBot</p>
      </div>
      <div class="user_item_icon icrank"><img src="default_images/rank/bot.svg" class="list_rank" title="Bot" /></div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="dropUser(this,3754679,'Fantastic',1,0,'ZZ','','14','');" class="avtrig user_item ">
      <div class="user_item_avatar"><img class="avav acav avsex nosex " src="/avatar/avatar_user3754679_1638955491.jpg" /> </div>
      <div class="user_item_data">
        <p class="username bcolor1 bnfont7">Fantastic</p>
        <p class="text_xsmall bustate bellips">TheDD7デイビスになる =</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="dropUser(this,4290052,'cefefef',0,0,'AU','','13','');" class="avtrig user_item ">
      <div class="user_item_avatar"><img class="avav acav avsex nosex " src="/avatar/default_guest.png" /> </div>
      <div class="user_item_data">
        <p class="username user ">cefefef</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="dropUser(this,4289985,'MeowCat',0,0,'AU','','13','');" class="avtrig user_item ">
      <div class="user_item_avatar"><img class="avav acav avsex nosex glob_av" src="/avatar/default_guest.png" /> </div>
      <div class="user_item_data">
        <p class="username user ">MeowCat</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>`;

function getUsers(str) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = str;
  return [...div.querySelectorAll('.user_item')].map(item => {
    let id = item.getAttribute('onclick').split(',')[1];
    let username = item.querySelector('.username').innerHTML;
    return {username, id};
  })
};
console.log(getUsers(htmlStr));
```

Comment: thats much more funny than doing leetcode... LOL

Comment: Thanks, This is 100% what i was trying to achieve I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have added two new attribute to each user_item Div instade of reading from html string as text. find **data-id** in this html.

```
let str =`<div id="container_user">
    <div class="user_count">
        <div class="bcell">
            Online <span class="ucount back_theme">4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="online_user">
        <div onclick="dropUser(this,5,'ChatAveBot',1,1,'ZZ','','0','');" class="avtrig user_item " data-id="1" data-name="ChatAveBot">
            <div class="user_item_avatar"><img class="avav acav avsex nosex " src="/avatar/default_avatar.png" /> </div>
            <div class="user_item_data">
                <p class="username user ">ChatAveBot</p>
            </div>
            <div class="user_item_icon icrank"><img src="default_images/rank/bot.svg" class="list_rank" title="Bot" /></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>`;
```

**Here is the Script to push all to in array**

```
const Users = [];
    $.each($(str).find('.user_item'), (userIndex, User) => {
        let _user = {};
        _user.id = $(User).attr('data-id');
        _user.Name = $(User).attr('data-name');
        Users.push(_user);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can suggest, as the original post has asked that the arguments passed to the dropUser function needs to be pushed in to an array. This solution is using regex and small string manipulations.

```
var regex=/dropUser\([A-Za-z0-9,'"]*\)/g;
var result=str.match(regex);
var argumentsArray = new Array();

result.forEach(input =>{ input = input.replace("dropUser(",""); input = input.replace('\)',''); argumentsArray.push(input) })
console.log(argumentsArray) //this will be a 2D array.
```

after this you should be able to extract the username and id, rather than reading from the .username label.